# How to set vertical orientation for text in table in code with Novacode DocX?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, docx, novacode-docx

Create and inserting Tables into documents is easy with `Novacode.DocX`.

```
// Create a document.
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Test.docx"))
{
// Add a Table to this document.
Table t = document.AddTable(2, 3);
// Specify some properties for this Table.
t.Alignment = Alignment.center;
t.Design = TableDesign.MediumGrid1Accent2;
// Add content to this Table.
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("A");
t.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("B");
t.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("C");
t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("D");
t.Rows[1].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("E");
t.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("F");
// Insert the Table into the document.
document.InsertTable(t);
document.Save();
}// Release this document from memory.
```

The above code will creates a document that looks like the below imag

And, How to set vertical orientation for text in table with DocX?
Text Orientation is made only from right to left or vice versa.

```
tablePlan.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Direction = Direction.LeftToRight;
```

And how to put from the bottom up?

[image]

Comment: By the way, where's the image.

Comment: Picture has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding:

```
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].TextDirection = TextDirection.btLr;
t.Rows[0].Cells[1].TextDirection = TextDirection.btLr;
t.Rows[0].Cells[2].TextDirection = TextDirection.btLr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a work around and only works if you already know the number of columns your Table is going to have before hand. You first need to create a document that contains a Table with the properties that you are looking for, text direction. You can then grab `Tables` as needed from the other template document.

```
// Create a document.
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Test.docx"))
{
    Table t;
    using (DocX document2 = DocX.Load(@"Test2.docx"))
    {
        t = document2.Tables[0];
    }        
    // Specify some properties for this Table.
    t.Alignment = Alignment.center;
    t.Design = TableDesign.MediumGrid1Accent2;
    // Add content to this Table.
    t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("A");
    t.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("B");
    t.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("C");
    t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("D");
    t.Rows[1].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("E");
    t.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("F");
    // Insert the Table into the document.
    document.InsertTable(t);
    document.Save();
}// Release this document from memory.
```

`document2` contains the table with properties that you are looking for.